# Как сделать "отступ" вокруг полосы прокрутки в HTML + CSS?

Tags: html, css

Я сделал стиль для полосы прокрутки с помощью webkit-scrollbar, но остался один вопрос: как сделать "отступ" вокруг полосы прокрутки? У меня получилось сделать это (часть элемента):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сделать нечто подобное:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Нативные скроллбары нельзя двигать вроде бы как.

Comment: паддинг внутри добавь